# Powerschool application (PowerTeacher) giving our entire district headaches (error messages inside)

Tags: java, http, runtime, powerschool

I am trying to update my students' grades in the PowerTeacher gradebook application made by Powerschool.

Sometimes it works wonderfully, but at other times (seems to mess up whenever grades are due...) it doesn't work at all.

It allows me to enter the assignment info into the gradebook, and to enter student grades on these respective assignments. However, when I go to save my work, it gives me a loading popup that says "Storing scores", and freezes up. It will then give me an error prompt with the following details:

```
com.pearson.powerschool.sdk.common.SDKRemoteException:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at com.pearson.powerschool.sdk.system.HttpInvokeInvocationHandler.invoke(HttpInvokeInvocationHandler.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.storeSectionScores(Unknown Source)
    at com.pearson.powerschool.gradebook.studentgrid.score.ScoreStoreTask.doConstruct(ScoreStoreTask.java:153)
    at com.pearson.powerschool.gradebook.SDKClientTask.construct(SDKClientTask.java:187)
    at com.pearson.powerschool.gradebook.SDKClientTask.execute(SDKClientTask.java:154)
    at com.pearson.powerschool.gradebook.SDKTaskManager.run(SDKTaskManager.java:59)

Caused By:java.net.SocketTimeoutException:Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:77)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1115)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1373)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1832)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1590)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:995)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
    at org.meno.remoting.httpinvoke.client.HTTPInvokeProxyFactory.invoke(HTTPInvokeProxyFactory.java:229)
    at org.meno.remoting.httpinvoke.client.HTTPInvokeProxyFactory.access$000(HTTPInvokeProxyFactory.java:42)
    at org.meno.remoting.httpinvoke.client.HTTPInvokeProxyFactory$1.invoke(HTTPInvokeProxyFactory.java:151)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.storeSectionScores(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.pearson.powerschool.sdk.system.HttpInvokeInvocationHandler.invoke(HttpInvokeInvocationHandler.java:48)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.storeSectionScores(Unknown Source)
    at com.pearson.powerschool.gradebook.studentgrid.score.ScoreStoreTask.doConstruct(ScoreStoreTask.java:153)
    at com.pearson.powerschool.gradebook.SDKClientTask.construct(SDKClientTask.java:187)
    at com.pearson.powerschool.gradebook.SDKClientTask.execute(SDKClientTask.java:154)
    at com.pearson.powerschool.gradebook.SDKTaskManager.run(SDKTaskManager.java:59)
```

I apologize for not being able to provide any more information. I don't have access to the code itself, or I would be busy looking at the various error locations. I'm hoping that someone may have encountered a similar error situation and may be able to describe the conditions under which the error occurs. I don't necessarily need to know how to fix the program (although I'm sure my superiors would be grateful for the info to send up the pipeline), I just want to know what NOT to do so that I can get my grades entered in by the deadline.

Thank you all very much for looking, and have a great day!

Comment: java.net.SocketTimeoutException:Read timed out - this means it took too long to get the requested results - either the network is performing poorly, or the database is very full and not performing optimally.

Comment: How does a database become "very full"? By each space where there could be data being assigned a value?

Comment: you could have a very small database with 30 students in one class - or your database could span 100 districts with millions of kids and grades..  my guess is your network and database are not sized correctly for the crush of everyone entering grades at the same time at the end of the semester.

Answer (score 0):

From https://powersource.pearsonschoolsystems.com/article/58431?from=search

**Summary**
This error can occur when launching PowerTeacher gradebook, an error is returned and the gradebook does not successfully launch or when performing an action in PowerTeacher gradebook, such as saving scores.

**Prerequisities**
•   When using PowerTeacher Gradebook on the server, the issue does not occur when using the internal address.
•   When outside the network, Issue not occur when Server Settings Web Server is set  to external IP address or external domain address.
•   Verified that Firewall is not blocking access.
•   Verified that Content filtering is not being used. 
•   Correct JAVA version is being used on client machine and server for the PowerSchool and/or PowerTeacher version.
•   Server environment settings are set to the correct Java version and location.

**Symptoms**
•   PowerTeacher gradebook fails to launch or save scores.
•   When clicking on the Details tab, the error shows as either "SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out"  or "SocketTimeoutException: read timed out" .

**Workaround(s)**
1 - 
    1.  On the client computer, click on the Start Menu.
    2.  Select Settings.
    3.  Select Control Panel.
    4.  Open the Java control panel.
    5.  Click Network Settings.
    6.  Change the setting to Direct Connection.
    7.  Click OK.
    8.  Click OK.
2-
    1.  Perform a manual resynchronization.
3- 
    1.  Restart Apache Tomcat.
Note
This may be  a client or networking environment issue.